# python regular expression to correct the following code

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need regular expression that converts "prooooooooooooof" into "proof"
for this i am using

```
import re
i='proooooooooooooooooof'
re.sub(r"(\w)\1*", r'\1',i)
```

but out put prints only "prof"

Comment: You should explain why `re.sub('proooooooooooooooooof', 'proof', i)` is not what you want.

Comment: You need to describe in English what you want to change.  We can't tell what your rules are.

Answer (score 1):

When using `(\w)\1*` for your example data, every first word character will be in the first capturing group. The possible following series of consecutive characters will be matched and are not part of the replacement. Using only `\1` in the replacement will use what is captured `p`, `r`, `o` and `f` resulting in `prof`

What you might do is repeat the capturing group 1+ times like `(\w)\1+`.  That will only capture the first `o` in the first capturing group because it should be repeated 1+ times instead of 0+ times and it will match the following `o`'s which will not be part of the replacement. Now you can use that capturing group 2 times in the replacement to get `proof`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H5vXYx/1) | [Python demo](https://rextester.com/PYLF88466)

```
import re
i='proooooooooooooooooof'
print(re.sub(r"(\w)\1+", r'\1\1',i))
```